# Stanislav Lem? Guy visits antimatter dimension, falls in love there

Tags: story-identification

I'm pretty sure this is a Soviet block story, so if it's not Stanislav Lem, then maybe someone Russian.

A guy has a device for sending simple substances (e.g. proteins) into an antimatter dimension. He also uses it for sending over messages written on paper. He gets messages back which shows him there's humans on the other side too. That way he starts talking to a girl from the other dimension, who is a kindergarten teacher. They fall in love and arrange a meeting.
He uses the device on himself and it works (or was it "almost works but with a catch"). In the antimatter dimension things are subtly different (weird, washed out colours etc). There he's arranged to meet the girl but she's late for the meeting.

In the antimatter dimension, unlike the regular dimension, he's a smoker.

The story ended with something like:

> ... and that's how he learned what is the difference between transferring a protein and a human being - **two burning eyes**...

Comment: Do you know what year you read it? Or when it was published?

Comment: @Edlothiad: I read it somewhere between 1997 and 2000. From the style the story was written in, I think it may have been written between 1940 and 1970, but I can't be sure.